# What does the second statement accomplish if the first has already disclaimed all warranties?

Tags: license-notice

[Ritchey Permissive License v7](https://jamesdanielmarrsritchey.blogspot.com/2019/12/ritchey-permissive-license-v7.html) states:

> provided without warranties of any kind. The authors, owners, and
>   providers will not be held responsible for anything

then states:

> When sharing the material with others you take on all responsibilities
>   of and relating to consequences (including warranties, implied
>   warranties, liabilities, and damages),

So what does the second statement accomplish, if the first has already disclaimed all warranties, and other responsibilities, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It accomplishes a couple things:

1. In a sharing chain it attempts to provide cumulative protection against reparations.

Let's pretend for a moment that the second statement doesn't exist. **Person A** publishes a shell script under the license, and **person B** downloads it. A bug in the script deletes all of the user's files in select scenarios. If **person B** decides to sue **person A**, **person A** should hopefully be protected by the disclaimer. Now let's expand this scenario. **Person B** downloads the script, and shares it to **person C**. **Person B** or **person C** could sue **person A**, but hopefully **person A** would be protected by the disclaimer. Now lets add that second statement back in. If **person B** attempts to sue **person A**, **person A** is hopefully protected by the disclaimer. If **person C** attempts to sue **person A**, **person A** is hopefully protected by both statements. If **person C** attempts to sue **person B**, **person B** is hopefully protected by the disclaimer. Now lets add another person to the mix. **Person C** shares the script with **person D**. If person **D decides** to sue **person A**, **person A** now potentially has 3 layers of protection, **person B** has 2 layers of protection, and **person C** has the standard 1 layer of protection. The second statement attempts to create cumulative protection against legal reparations for each person in the sharing chain.

2. It attempts to protect the owner from reparations when others redistribute without the license included.

Let's say **person A** publishes a shell script under the license. A bug in the script deletes all of the user's files in select scenarios. **Person B** then downloads it, and shares it with **person C**. However **person B** didn't include a copy of the license when he shared it. Remember the license doesn't require retention of the license. **Person B** received it with the license so it's likely he saw the disclaimer, and **person A** is hopefully protected. **Person C** didn't get a copy of the license though which means she never saw any disclaimer, **and therefore nothing was disclaimed to her!** The second statement should hopefully protect **person A** in this scenario from **person C**. **Person B** on the other hand may not be protected. The second statement allows for users to share the work without retaining the license, but makes it their risk to take, rather than leaving the script owner responsible for their actions.

#### Related Reading:

- https://writing.kemitchell.com/2018/08/28/Unhappy-Coincidences.html#attribution-doesnt-mean-credit
- https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/do-warranty-disclaimers-in-software-licenses-carry-any-legal-weight
- https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5202/is-it-possible-to-distribute-bsd-derived-software-with-a-warranty?rq=1